# translate attribute values with ngx-translate angular

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I am trying to use ngx-translate for attribute values like 
  p-messages text, 
  p-column header,
  p-tabPanel header

```
<p-message text="text"></p-message>

<p-column header="text"></p-column>

<p-tabPanel header="text">
```

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
<p-tabPanel header="'key' | translate">

<p-tabPanel header="{{'key' | translate}}">

<p-tabPanel [attr.header]="'key' | translate">
```

Is there any way to use ngx-translate for these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution worked:

```
 <p-tabPanel header="{{'key' | translate}}">
```

But be very careful to import TranslateModule in the needed module.

Answer (score 1):

From [this github issue](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/496)

```
<img src="image.jpg" [attr.alt]="'key' | translate"> or like this:
<input placeholder="{{'key' | translate}}">
```

Comment: Thank you for your response @Ferenc. I tried this model for my situation like this and it doesn't work:
<p-tabPanel [attr.header]="'key' | translate">

Comment: That's odd. Does [this fiddle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-gpzrj9-ljy86a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) help at all?

Comment: After seeing this fiddle, I realized that the problem was not importing TranslateModule in the right module, which contained the components. So thank you for your help and time.

The following worked:
<p-tabPanel header="{{'key' | translate}}">